# fail to convert series to a string object

Tags: python, string

I am new to Python, so i understand how basic my question is. The thing is that I seem to have converted a Series into a str object, yet I still can not apply the isupper function tha I guess I need for the package to work.

```
data_4['sex'] = np.where((data_4['anthro_female']=='male'), 'M', 'F')
#data_4['sex']=helpers.get_good_sex('male')
#data_4["sex"].astype('category')

#data_4.sex.to_string()
#data_4['sex'].astype(str)
#data_4['sex']= data_4['sex'].astype(str)
data_4['sex'] = pd.Series(data_4['sex'], dtype="string")
data_4["sex"]= data_4["sex"].astype(str)
data_4['sex'] = data_4['sex'].astype('|S80')
#data_4['sex'] = pd.Series(data_4['sex'], dtype=pd.StringDtype)
data_4['z_height'] = Calculator.zscore_for_measurement('lhfa', measurement=data_4.length,
                                                       age_in_months=data_4.anthro_age, 
                                                       sex = str.isupper(data_4['sex']), indicator = 'lhfa' )
data_4.head(10)
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-7965ec9e2ad5> in <module>
     12 data_4['z_height'] = Calculator.zscore_for_measurement('lhfa', measurement=data_4.length,
     13                                                        age_in_months=data_4.anthro_age,
---> 14                                                        sex = str.isupper(data_4['sex']), indicator = 'lhfa' )
     15 data_4.head(10)

TypeError: descriptor 'isupper' requires a 'str' object but received a 'Series'
```

**UPD:**
when typing `sex = str.isupper(data_4['sex'].to_string())`  instead the following error returns:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-9424df958115> in <module>
     12 data_4['z_height'] = Calculator.zscore_for_measurement('lhfa', measurement=data_4.length,
     13                                                        age_in_months=data_4.anthro_age,
---> 14                                                        sex = str.isupper(data_4['sex'].to_string()), indicator = 'lhfa' )
     15 data_4.head(10)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygrowup\pygrowup.py in zscore_for_measurement(self, indicator, measurement, age_in_months, sex, height)
    316     def zscore_for_measurement(self, indicator, measurement, age_in_months, sex, height=None):
    317         assert sex is not None
--> 318         assert isinstance(sex, six.string_types)
    319         assert sex.upper() in ["M", "F"]
    320         assert age_in_months is not None

AssertionError:
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make it work by changing `str.isupper(data_4['sex'])` to `str.isupper(data_4['sex'].to_string())`.

Basically, the problem here is that `data_4['sex']` is not a string but a Pandas Series that contains a string. If you're familiar with any worksheet software like Excel, you can picture this difference as the difference between a cell and the text that is contained within the cell. Here, you want to give the descriptor isupper the text, i.e. the string, and not the cell, i.e. the Pandas Series object.

Comment: thanks a lot for the feedback! unfortunately, in that case i get another error "assert isinstance(sex, six.string_types)"

Comment: Can you copy and paste here the entire new error? Sorry that my first answer did not work!

Comment: yes sure, can it be the case that the package and my python version are different and that is why

Comment: Most probably not! So I don't know the package from which the function ```Calculator.zscore_for_measurement``` comes, but it seems like the variable ```sex``` needs to be a string, and not a list, or a Pandas Series, or anything else. So it should either be "M" or "F" but it does seem like it can't be something like ["F", "M", "M", ...].

Comment: I see, yeah I was thinking maybe I should loop over the rows, but decided not to. the official example on how to use the package shows it only on one observation https://pypi.org/project/pygrowup/, so I think what I'm doing wrong is that I fail to adjust the code to a dataframe as opposed to if it were only one observation.